# Logstash - Parsing Optional Logs through Custom grok pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, logstash, option-type, logstash-grok, logparser

Following is my log patterns

```
Sample 1 :
2022-06-14 02:03:22.051  INFO  [ServiceName,TraceId,SpanID] 109171 --- [Thread] ClassName : A=ValueA B=ValueB C=ValueC

Sample 2:
2022-06-14 02:03:22.051  INFO  [ServiceName,TraceId,SpanID] 109171 --- [Thread] ClassName : D=ValueD B=ValueB C=ValueC

Sample 3:
2022-06-14 02:03:22.051  INFO  [ServiceName,TraceId,SpanID] 109171 --- [Thread] ClassName : D=ValueD E=ValueE C=ValueC F=ValueF

Sample 4:
INFO  [ServiceName,TraceId,SpanID] 109171 --- [Thread] ClassName : Some Log Message
```

Following is the grok pattern I tried

Custom Patterns:
A A=.*A
B B=.*B and similar

For Example following log pattern :

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}?%{SPACE}*%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}%{SPACE}*\[%{DATA:service},%{DATA:ZTraceId},%{DATA:ZSpanId}\]%{SPACE}*%{NUMBER:ProcessId}%{GREEDYDATA:message}%{A:Afield}
```

Above log works in Sample1 but not 2,3 &4

`%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}`? ---- Optional way works in all samples

At the same time,
`%{A:Afield}`? Doesnt work in Sample 1,2,3,4....In Sample Afield is not identified

Can anyone please provide a solution for optional custom grok pattern

Comment: For the `A=ValueA B=ValueB C=ValueC` part of the message, you should just store in a field and use the [kv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) on that field

Answer (score 0):

You can try this grok pattern which might help

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}?%{SPACE}*%{DATA:log-level}?%{SPACE}*\[%{DATA:service}\,%{DATA:ZTraceId}\,%{DATA:ZSpanId}\] %{NUMBER:ProcessId} --- \[%{DATA:buglevel}\] %{DATA:class}: %{GREEDYDATA:message} %{GREEDYDATA:message} %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```